# Cronjob log messages

Tags: magento, cron

After some difficulties with my cronjobs in Magento, i want to customize the log-messages sent after i.e. reindex process.

> Stock Status index was rebuilt successfully
>
> Product Attributes index was rebuilt successfully
>
> Product Prices index was rebuilt successfully
>
> Product Attributes index was rebuilt successfully
>
> Product Prices index was rebuilt successfully
>
> Product Attributes index was rebuilt successfully
>
> Product Prices index was rebuilt successfully

I want to add i.e. a timestamp, but i don't find where to change or edit these success/error messages.

In my magento installation there are every night about 15 cronjobs running, and i want to log all cronjobs in one logfile with start timestamp, end timestamp and success/error.

Answer (score 0):

I think this brilliant Fabrizio Branca's extension could help you to track cron jobs processes (I'm not his affiliate:)) It's free and you can download it from [Fabrizio site](http://www.fabrizio-branca.de/magento-cron-scheduler.html)  where you can find some info on how extension works or from [Magento Connect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html)